# Google Apps Script -Advanced Calendar Service

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar

I want to share a google Sheet with users that allows them to add a multi all-day event to their calendar. As google doesnt provide a function to do that I have tired various workarounds. 
The createEvent(title, startTime, endTime) isnt perfect as it uses and shows datetime, 
createEventFromDescription(description) doesnt allow meta data such as description and so I have tried using the Advanced Calendar Service. 
From what I have read once you have enabled the Advanced Calendar Service you should be able to use the Google Calendar API as if you were using the App Script's built-in Calendar Service . If I run this built-in function in a sheets script editor it works and I can make a copy of the sheet, email it to someone else and they can also run the function
    `var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent('Apollo 
    11 Landing',
     new Date('July 20, 1969 20:00:00 UTC'),
     new Date('July 20, 1969 21:00:00 UTC'),
     {location: 'The Moon'});
     Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());`
 If I use the Advanced Calendar Service and use the code below which is basically their example, I can run the function in the Script Editor and it works but if I make a copy of the sheet and email it to someone else to try I get the error "Project (number) is not found and cannot be used for API calls" . Can anyone see what I am doing wrong.

```
function createEvent() {
var calendarId = 'primary';

var event = {
summary: 'Lunch Meeting',
location: 'The Deli',
description: 'To discuss our plans for the presentation next week.',
start: {
  date: "2017-05-21"
},
end: {
  date: "2017-05-24"
},
attendees: [
  {email: 'alice@example.com'},
  {email: 'bob@example.com'}
],
// Red background. Use Calendar.Colors.get() for the full list.
colorId: 11
};
event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);
Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I don't know why you're getting the API call error; however, `createEventFromDescription` returns an event object, so you could add a description like so:

```
var event = createEventFromDescription("Some event 4/25 - 4/30");
event.setDescription("This is a description.");
```

The `CalendarApp` isn't as robust as the Advanced Calendar Service (for example you can't set an events color), but it might suit your purposes enough to get by.

Comment: I meant thanks for that. I will use that if I cant get the Advanced Calendar Service to work

Comment: I guess my question really is..can you share a sheet that has a script that uses the Advanced Calendar Service by simply making a copy of the sheet.

Comment: The answer is yes but the person who you share it with also has to enable the Calendar API

Comment: Yeah, won't they need to open the script editor and then the advanced services script? Not too user friendly